# Поиск в Stream Java и обработка исключений java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: java, исключения, java-8, java-stream

Есть поиск в коллекции:

```
for (Object dataRow : objects) {
    AttributeModel attribute = document.getAttributeModels().stream()
    .filter(atr -> atr.getName().equals(nameField)).findFirst().get();
....
....
}
```

но если элемента с таким именем нету в коллекции, вы,выбрасывает ошибку :

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value
>   present

Как правильно обработать эту ошибку в стриме?
И как можно сделать, чтобы при отсутствии элемента, выполнялся следующий цикл for() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод Optional.get() только после проверки Optional.isPresent()

```
for (Object dataRow : objects) {
    Optional<AttributeModel> opt = document.getAttributeModels()
    .stream()
    .filter(atr -> atr.getName().equals(nameField))
    .findFirst();
    if (opt.isPresent()){
      AttributeModel attribute = opt.get();
    } 
....
....
}
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо. А я думал куда приткнуть  isPresent()  :)